# "Normal Map" Node vs "Normal" Node?

Tags: shaders

What is the difference between the *Normal Map* Node and the *Normal* Node? When do you use one over the other?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Normal node sets a normal vector (default at right angle to surface tangent) which can be manipulated by dragging the sphere around - the dot output gives the dot product of the angles of the 2 spheres (can be manipulated separately). The Normal Map node is responsible for mapping a bitmap image texture ("purple" normal map texture) and translating that into usable surface normal vectors.